# How to run logstash docker container on python script with 2 another python script

Tags: python, docker, logstash

I need to run logstash container with 2 python script. What does it mean:

I have 2 python scripts and 1 docker container.
I need to run logstash container then run sender.py and validater.py

sender.py send some data to docker container on tcp. Logstash takes those data and give me output.json then validater.py check output if the objects are valid or not.

I can do these processes manually but I need one more python script to do all these things automatically.

To run docker container: I use something like(this is not all):

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/config-dir logstash-con -f /config-dir/logstash-conf.config
```

Does anyone know how to do this in single python script.
Thank you

Comment: Are you searching for Python SDK to run docker commands or are you searching for a simply Python command to run a terminal command? Run the Python scripts also in a docker container or locally?

Comment: Actually both. I need python script to run docker container, sender.py and validater.py. These two python script should run locally.

Comment: Take a look into https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. And the `Subprocess` module to call terminal commands.